# how to let entity read db configuration

Tags: java, jpa, architecture, ejb

Consider the problem of entities that need to read some database configuration in order set some values :
for example :

```
@entity
public class person{
int age,
String ageCategory;
}
```

**ageCategory** will be fetched from the database when **age** is set.
my question what is the best EJB architecture to use in order to read **AgeCategoryConfiguration**  from the databse. currently i am using **jndi** to inject the **AgeCategoryFacade** which provide a method to get **AgeCategory** from age, this method is called in the **age** **setter**.

is there a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to look  at [jpa Events](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Events) .

You stated that **ageCategory** will be fetched from the database when age is set this and i think this statement fits [@PostLoad](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PostLoad.html) annotation.

If you want to know more read [this nice article](http://java.boot.by/scbcd5-guide/ch06s04.html). And usually you should not need jndi paths while  injecting ejbs.

Edit
I would keep things as simple as possible.

So you should have some bean which is used in JSF with method for updating person:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class PersonController {

    @Inject
    private PersonService personService;

    private Person selectedPerson;

    /**
     * Method for updating.
     */
    public void updatePerson(ActionEvent actionEvent){
        Person updatedPerson = personService.update(selectedUser);
        // pass updatedPerson to presentation layer..
    }
}
```

Next you should have PersonService which takes care of Person's [CRUD operations](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/generic_crud_service_aka_dao):

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class PersonService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Inject
    private AgeCategoryFacade ageCategoryFacade;

    public Person updatePerson(Person person) {
         // use ageCategoryFacade somehow to set ageCategory for example:
         String ageCategory = ageCategoryFacade.getAgeCategory(person.getAge());
         person.setAgeCategory(ageCategory);
         return (Person) em.merge(person);
    }
}
```

Note that you can use ageCategoryFacade also in **other methods** like createPerson, findPerson.

Solution with JPA events involves PostLoad(or PrePersist) method in entity Bean:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    int age;
    String ageCategory;

    /**
     * Simple setting of ageCategory.
     */
    @PostLoad
    public void postLoadPerson {
        if(age < 10) {
            setAgeCategory("A");
        } else if (age < 30) {
            setAgeCategory("B");
        } else {
            setAgeCategory("C");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: postload will be called when age setter called. i9 believe you need to reread the nice article you mentioned . postload usually called when entity is fetched from the database. beside suppose i used jpa events such as prepersist/merge  is it a good approach to inject agecategoryfacade in the event.

Comment: I thought you have some policy in AgeCategoryConfiguration which describes how the field ageCategory should look like. When you use this policy before persisting/merging of course it will work and will be more effective. BUT you cannot change AgeCategoryConfiguration's rules without getting non-consistent data.

Comment: my question is : if entity need to access the database . is injection session bean inside entity is right approach

Comment: the problem is in fetching.

Comment: I don't really know if injecting session bean into entity is even possible, never tried that. And I would use PrePersist/PostLoad only for some simple field setting, if there is something more complex it should be in businnes logic(method in session bean, where you save/load entity beans), because I don't want to have logic of saving/loading on different places(session+entity bean), but that is just my opinion.

Comment: i agree not to have entity inject session bean , for that i am asking about a methodology to solve such problem. setter are called implicitly by jsf(presentation layer) , EJB(business layer) must provide a way to set the other field without disturbing the simplicity of binding. how about using property change listener?? so fetching will be done by the property listener which will inject the session bean. @Joe

Comment: I have updated the answer, using propertychangeListener is kind of "hacking" for me. I still don't get it why do you want to set ageCategory "immediately" after age is set but not when update request is called.

Comment: hehehe (ethical one) , the setting immediately is due to requirement, when user set the birth year the agecategory field must be set (by ajax), before the user decide to save.

Comment: So you can use AgeCategoryFacade for obtaining ageCategory exactly in method for ajax request when age field is set(or changed)?

Comment: yup,thats a solution but i want it to set automatically, since this problem is found in  a lot of scenario. and i am wondering is there a common method to solve such problem.